# UnicodeDecodeError for medieval characters

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, nltk

I am trying to run an nltk tokenize program on medieval texts. These texts use medieval characters such as yogh (ȝ), thorn (þ), and eth (ð).

When I run the program (pasted below) with standard unicode (utf-8) encoding, I get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "me_scraper_redux2.py", line 11, in <module>
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize( open( "ME_Corpus_sm/"+file, encoding="utf_8" ).read() )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 313, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte`

I have tried other encodings, such as latin1, etc., and these circumvent the problem, but then I don't get accurate results as those encodings use other characters to fill the space. I thought that unicode could handle these characters. Am I doing something wrong, or is there another encoding I should use? The files were originally in utf-8.
See my code below:

```
import nltk
import os, os.path
import string

from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

files = os.listdir("ME_Corpus_sm/")
for file in files:
    # open, parse, and normalize the tokens (words) in the file
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize( open( "ME_Corpus_sm/"+file, encoding="utf_8" ).read() )
    tokens = [ token.lower() for token in tokens ]
    tokens = [ ''.join( character for character in token if character not in string.punctuation ) for token in tokens ]
    tokens = [ token for token in tokens if token.isalpha() ]
    tokens = [ token for token in tokens if not token in stopwords.words( 'english' ) ]

# output maximum most frequent tokens and their counts
    for tuple in nltk.FreqDist( tokens ).most_common( 50 ):
        word  = tuple[ 0 ]
        count = str( tuple[ 1 ] )
        print(word + "\t" + count)
```

Comment: Could you post a *very* small excerpt of the text, containing, say, a thorn (possibly the binary hex or base64 encoding of said excerpt)? The error ("invalid start byte 0x80") seems to point to invalid UTF-8, since 0x80 is a 10xxxxxx byte which ought to be a *continuation* code, never to be found at the start of a token. It can be encountered in ISO-8859-15 (Latin1) texts, though...

Comment: FYI Unicode is *not* UTF-8.

Comment: Martin, thank you, I am still wrapping my head around these things!

Comment: lserni, thanks for your help. Hopefully bobince's response will save us having to inspect the binary for now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file isn't valid UTF-8.

Maybe it's partly UTF-8 and partly some other junk? You could try:

```
open(..., encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
```

to replace non-UTF-8 sequences with question marks instead of raising an error, which might give you a chance to see where the problem lies. In general if you have a mix of encodings in a single file you're pretty much doomed as they can't be reliably picked apart.

Comment: bobince, for whatever reason, I had not done that yet. I have done so now, and it worked just fine. All of the thorns and eths and yoghs are showing up fine, so I'm not sure where the problem was. On a cursory look at the text (it is some 2000 lines long), I couldn't even see any obvious amount of non-punctuation-related question marks. Thank you so much!